# How to swipeToRefresh when recyclerView is not visible?

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

I'm new in Android, so can't find the answer how to make SwipeToRefresh shown when RecyclerView is empty.

**Prerequisites:** In code below I show TextView with "no data" text in case I got no data from server. 
If there is some data from server, I init adapter and set it to RecyclerView.

**Problem:** Can't refresh the page using SwipeToRefresh when TextView with "no data" is shown.
If there is some data in recyclerView - swipeToRefresh works good.

Thank you in advance.

```
    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/recycler_view_tab"
            style="@style/RecyclerStyle"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:clipToPadding="false"
            android:paddingBottom="@dimen/padding_card_view"
            android:paddingLeft="@dimen/padding_card_view"
            android:paddingRight="@dimen/padding_card_view" />

        <ProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/pb_tab"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:indeterminate="true"
            android:layout_gravity="center" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_no_data"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/tab_the_list_is_empty"
            android:textColor="@color/hintTextColor"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:visibility="gone" />

        <ProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/pb_tab2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:indeterminate="true"
            style="?android:attr/progressBarStyle"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|bottom"
            android:visibility="gone" />

    </FrameLayout>

</android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>


/**
 * Make request for get model
 */
@Override
public void getModel(int page, int positionTab) {
    mTvNoData.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    mPbTab.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    mPresenter.getModel(context, page, positionTab);
}

/**
 * Get list model and load/refresh adapter
 */
@Override
public void getModelResponse(List<AllTasksModel> allTasksModels, boolean isLoading) {
    mIsLoading = isLoading;
    mListItems = allTasksModels;
    mPbTab.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    mPbTab2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    if (mListItems.size() == 0) {
        mTvNoData.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    } else {
        mAdapter = new TabJobsRecyclerAdapter(context, mListItems, this);
        mRecViewTab.setAdapter(mAdapter);
    }
}
```

Comment: are you setting the `adapter` when there is no data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change

**From:**

```
@Override
public void getModelResponse(List<AllTasksModel> allTasksModels, boolean isLoading) {
    mIsLoading = isLoading;
    mListItems = allTasksModels;
    mPbTab.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    mPbTab2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    if (mListItems.size() == 0) {
        mTvNoData.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    } else {
        mAdapter = new TabJobsRecyclerAdapter(context, mListItems, this);
        mRecViewTab.setAdapter(mAdapter);
    }
}
```

**To:**

```
@Override
public void getModelResponse(List<AllTasksModel> allTasksModels, boolean isLoading) {
    mIsLoading = isLoading;
    mListItems = allTasksModels;
    mPbTab.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    mPbTab2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    mAdapter = new TabJobsRecyclerAdapter(context, mListItems, this);
    mRecViewTab.setAdapter(mAdapter);
    if (mListItems.size() == 0) {
        mTvNoData.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    } else {
        mTvNoData.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
}
```

Basically I am setting the adapter no matter how many data is there, so that swipeToRefresh will work even when there are no items in the `listView`. 
I have one suggestion though, try making the `ListView` as immediate child of `SwipeRefreshLayout` instead of having `FrameLayout` in the middle of view hierarchy.

Comment: Thank you. And you are right about unnecessary FrameLayout.

Answer (score 0):

The swipe-to-refresh gesture is all based around the scrolling list view.  When updates are entering at the top of the list, pulling the list down means you want to see the newest content.  So the pull-down gesture is natural for starting a refresh.

You need to do one of two things:

1. Put your "No Data" `TextView` *underneath* your `RecyclerView` with no data in it, so the user can see the `TextView` and still swipe down on the empty `RecyclerView`.
2. Put an additional "Refresh" button next to the "No Data" `TextView`.  This button would only be shown when the `TextView` is shown.